# illustrator cs5- paste in place not changing layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to re-organize a project that has gotten a lot of objects stuck in the wrong layers.

For some reason when I select a group of objects and try to move them to another artboard my paste in place command does not move them to the new layer I select. If I try a standard paste operation and choose to re-align the object I find that it also does not paste to the correct layer.

My layers are all visible and not locked. Grouped/ungrouped objects have same behavior.

Has my project corrupted or is this something simple I don't know about?

Comment: ok well if I turn my resolution WAY up and expand the layers to see the objects on the layer I find that I can drag between and actually get my objects to move. Still don't understand why the paste in place wont do this though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the Layer panel fly-out menu. There is an option for "paste remembers layers". Could that be your problem?

Comment: Yep that was it. I had planned to work with that option always enabled but now I see a really good reason not to :).

Answer (score 1):

1. Be certain to **deselect everything** - <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Win)  - and then highlight
   the layer you want to paste onto ***before*** pasting in place. If you have objects selected when pasting, the paste command uses the top-most layer with a selected object.
2. What plainclothes posted, be certain "Paste Remembers layers" is
   **not** checked in the Layer Panel flyout menu.